# Why is ngOnchanges not firing when a boolean value changed in angularjs 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have seen similar questions on this issue but non of the answers worked for me. I have a boolean value that change whenever an async task has been completed, but it's strange that ngonchages does not fire anytime it changes. Below is my code:

```
import {
    Component,
    OnChanges,
    SimpleChange
} from '@angular/core';
export class HomePage implements OnChanges {

    isLoaded: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.isLoaded = false;
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.isLoaded = true;
            console.log(this.isLoaded);
        }, 3000);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log("There has been a change ", changes); //this is not firing
    }
}
```

Comment: Either `isLoaded` should be there on view `bindings`/`@input` property..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ngOnChanges` is a lifecycle callback of Angulars change detection mechanism and it is called when an `@Input()` is changed by Angulars data binding

When you have

```
@Input() isLoaded: boolean;
```

and

```
<home-page [isLoaded]="someValue">
```

and `someValue` in the parent component is changed, then change detection updates `isLoaded` and calls `ngOnChanges()`.

For your case the simplest solution is probably using a getter instead of a property:

```
_isLoaded: boolean;
set isLoaded(value:bool) {
  this._isLoaded = value;
  this.doSomething(value)
}
get isLoaded() {
  return this._isLoaded;
}
```

Comment: I know about getter and setter but this wont work for this scenario. The app need to watch for the isLoaded value so that it can manipulate the DOM after a response from the server

Comment: Why do you think the setter is not waiting for the isLoaded value?

Comment: I have to use the getter and setter for now. But am still going to read more about onChanges.

Answer (score 0):

Property treated as input (part of checking changes) should be marked with @Input

```
@Input()
isLoaded: boolean;
```